# Best practice: how to return keyset of a map from a method in java

Tags: java, dictionary

My function returns a keyset of a HashMap member.

From [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29):

> > The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa.

I want to avoid this behavior.

I want to return an unmodifiable set, perhaps a copy of the set.

I do not want changes to the set or map to be reflected in one another.

Are there any best practices to deal with such a situation?

Comment: Are you worried about mutating the structure of the set,  mutating the properties of the items in the set, or both?  If you're only worried about the first thing, just create a new Set: `Set<Foo> freshSet = new HashSet<Foo>(map.keySet());`

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd go with Google's Guava - especially for *I want to return an unmodifiable set, perhaps a copy of the set.* - if the map grows, `ImmutableSet` won't exhibit growth:

`ImmutableSet.copyOf(map.keySet());`

Or if you want to use the standard Java API - NOTE the resulting `Set` will grow as your `Map` grows:

`Collections.unmodifiableSet(map.keySet());`

Using either of the above is considered good practice given your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach is to return a copy, typically using a [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor):

Here's a utility method you can use:

```
public static <K, V> Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> copyKeys(Map<K, V> map) {
    return new HashSet<Map.Entry<K, V>>(map.keySet());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard `Collections.unmodifiableSet` which is designed exactly for that. Attempts to modify the wrapped Set will end up in `UnsupportedOperationException`